# How to find the ID of a dynamic UI element in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

I can make the dynamic UI without problems, but I don't know how to access the view with findviewbyid (R.id._____) I don't know what to put in the blank.

.java code

```
public class newList extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnAddItem;

RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_list);

    // allows the creation of dynamic rows


    btnAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addItem);

    btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearVert);
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows, parent);



        }
    });

   }
}
```

xml that is associated with the java file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.app.shoppingbuddy.shoppingbuddy.newList">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearVert">



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Subtotal"
    android:id="@+id/subtotal"
    android:textColor="#ffc800"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tax"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Tax"
    android:id="@+id/tax"
    android:textColor="#ee00ff"
    android:layout_above="@+id/total"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Total"
    android:id="@+id/total"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/subtotalAmount"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/subtotal"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/scrollView"
    android:textColor="#ffc800" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/taxAmount"
    android:layout_above="@+id/total"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="#ee00ff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/totalAmount"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/total"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/taxAmount"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Item"
    android:id="@+id/addItem"
    android:layout_above="@+id/subtotal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml used to create rows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/linearHor">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:src="@drawable/box"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemName"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_weight="0.78" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/itemPrice"
        android:hint="$ Price" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no unique `R.id` value at the activity level. For example, suppose the user taps the button 10 times, so you inflate the `R.layout.rows` layout 10 times. As a result, there will be 10 `R.id.linearHor` widgets, 10 `R.id.itemPrice` widgets, and so on.

Always call `findViewById()` on something that is guaranteed to give you a unique result. In this case — as with `ListView`, `GridView`, `RecyclerView`, etc. — you need to use other approaches to find the correct row `View`, then call `findViewById()` on that `View` to get at its child widgets.

Comment: So how would I go about finding the correct view row?

Comment: @SCREAM2NIGHT, You could use `view.setID` to set a specific id when creating them, and then use that Id with `findViewById(..)`. You could also use something like ListView instead, which is designed to handle things like lists, and is also more efficient.

Comment: @SCREAM2NIGHT: Since I have no idea how you are using this, I cannot really answer that. You could keep an `ArrayList<View>` or a `HashMap<SomethingOrAnother, View>` if you want.